# "Direction" or "instruction" or other: outsourcing illustrations

Tags: differences

I want to outsource illustrations. I'm writing a document to specify requirements (the sizes, resolution, what to include in, pose of a character, etc...).

What's the apt name for this document? Illustration Directions? Illustration Instructions? Or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known as an **Illustration brief**.

> [How to brief an illustrator](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-brief-illustrator-practical-example-nicolene-louw)
>   "I use this illustration I have recently done for a publisher as an example. They did a superb job on the **brief** and made the project much easier.
>   You need to include the following items in your **brief**: ..."

[Creative Bloq](https://www.creativebloq.com/illustration/techniques-tackling-illustration-brief-11619018) :-

> Nine Techniques for Tackling **Illustration Briefs**

Comment: I edited in order to add the actual expression 'illustration briefs'. Feel free to revert if you wish.